# Let $a, b, m$ be positive integers such that $m \space | \space (a - b)$, Prove by induction on $k \geq 0$ that $m \space | \space (a^k - b^k)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Given:

- $a, b, m$ are positive integers
- Since $m \space | \space (a - b)$, then  $m \space | \space a$ and  $m \space | \space b$

I can work my way around these when approaching normal proof, but I have no clue how to approach this from an induction standpoint.

A solution is very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What is the structure of a proof by induction? (And is this homework, as one would suspect?)

Comment: My apologies, I proved the basis step and the induction hypothesis. I just didn't write them in the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base case: $k=0$ is true, also $k=1$ is true by given condition.

Assume $k=n$ is true, $m|(a^n-b^n)$

For $k=n+1$,

$$a^{n+1}-b^{n+1}=a^{n+1}-ab^n+ab^n-b^{n+1}$$

Can you proceed from here?

Comment: Yeah, that's the direction I needed. Thank you!

Comment: Don't answer a low quality question. This type of question will be deleted in future and your hard earned reputation...

Comment: got it, thank you! @LostinSpace